# Reusing form_for in view for a mailer errors on forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, actionview, form-helpers

I have a form_for in a template new.html.erb where I do the normal save to the DB and then an e-mail on success. I want the mailer to send the same new.html.erb as the body and pass the model so that the form is fully populated. I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x000000049d7110>:0x000000049d4690>
```

On the line immediately after the form_for tag (since it's injecting the auth token tag I think). Is there a way I can circumvent this so that I can re-use the template in the mailer?

Here's what the mailer code looks like

```
class MaintenanceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application  

  def request_email(maintenance)
    mail :to => maintenance.community.email, :subject => "Maintenance" do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'default', :template => 'maintenance/new' }
    end    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this to a helper that only your mailer template uses:

```
    def protect_against_forgery?
      false
    end
```

But make sure that the receiving controller skips the verify_authenticity_token, and that session jacking is ok for whatever that form carries.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it gives me another error:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

I want that action to verify authenticity on a normal page request for the form. Do I need to send something to the controller once I'm in the mailer? All it should have to do is now render that "new" template w/o going back to the controller.

Comment: Yes, that's the skips "verify_authenticity_token" part. The syntax to do that in your controller (at the top) is:


    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:my_form_action]

Answer (score 4):

I used the method Sam C suggested, but slightly adjusted it. Just before calling the render to string, I override the method.

```
ApplicationHelper.send(:define_method, :protect_against_forgery?) { false }
html = render_to_string(template: "quotations/show", layout: "application_print")
```

This overrides the protect_against_forgery? method temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem working in a house sales page. Are you using form_for in your email template? Because this was my trouble, I built it using div's instead form_for and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can just turn off the authenticity of the form_for in the template.new.html to avoid such errors

you can check this for
[How do i remove the authenticity_token from rails forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074945/how-do-i-remove-the-authenticity-token-from-rails-forms)

Comment: I understand you are not eligible to post a comment yet. When posting links in / as an answer, try summarizing on the main idea that the link might elaborate on.