# How do i remove the authenticity_token from rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have worked out how to disable the authenticity_token in the controller but rails still creates the field in the forms. How do i turn this off as the server i am posting the form to needs a very specific set of field names.

Comment: let's write this in your controller: skip_before_filter :protect_from_forgery, and you can through authenticity token and CSRF. But this solution is NOT remove authenticity_token...;( I also want to know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In rails after 3.2.x you can pass a parameter into the form generator as suggested in another answer:

```
form_for @invoice, :url => external_url, :authenticity_token => false do |f|
  ...
<% end %>
```

In any rails version you can disable globally in config/application.rb, as in another answer:

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

In rails 3.0.x you can disable on a page load basis in the controller by overriding the following method. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to do this at the form level.

```
protected
  def protect_against_forgery?
    if ...
      # results in the meta tag being ommitted and no forms having authenticity token
      return false 
    else
      # default implementation based on global config
      return allow_forgery_protection 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable it across your application, you can add this line to your config/application.rb:

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
```

Comment: This is a global setting, which is unlikely what anyone would want.

Answer (score 1):

For external urls you can turn this of per form as follows:

```
<%= form_for @invoice, :url => external_url, :authenticity_token => false do |f|
  ...
<% end %>
```

Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for